# How to use pandas Styler to escape percentage for LaTeX

Tags: pandas, latex, pandas-styles

I would like to export a dataframe containing percentage values like

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0.2323, 0.5254, 1], columns=['c'])
```

to LaTeX which can be done by

```
df.style.format('{:.2%}').to_latex()
```

This returns

```
\begin{tabular}{lr}
 & c \\
0 & 23.23% \\
1 & 52.54% \\
2 & 100.00% \\
\end{tabular}
```

which is obviously no valid TeX code since `%` is not properly escaped. How do I do that?

```
df.to_latex(float_format='{:0.2%}'.format)
```

would work but I get a deprecation warning:

```
FutureWarning: In future versions `DataFrame.to_latex` is expected to utilise the base implementation of `Styler.to_latex` for formatting and rendering. The arguments signature may therefore change. It is recommended instead to use `DataFrame.style.to_latex` which also contains additional functionality.
```

Comment: The `format(escape="latex")` does not work here because escaping is done before the formatter. Carlos' solution is best. Just encode the escape character into your formatting function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a wonderful tool that does what I need wonderfully: [`tabulate`](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/)

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0.2323, 0.5254, 1], columns=['c'])
print(tabulate(df, intfmt=",", floatfmt='.2%', tablefmt='latex', headers=df.columns))
```

prints

```
\begin{tabular}{rr}
\hline
    &       c \\
\hline
  0 &  23.23\% \\
  1 &  52.54\% \\
  2 & 100.00\% \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Yet another option could be [`texttable`](https://github.com/JAEarly/latextable) (or its latex-focused extensions [`latextable`](https://github.com/JAEarly/latextable)), but I haven't checked them yet.

Answer (score 3):

My approach:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([0.2323, 0.5254, 1], columns=['c'])
df.style.format(lambda s: '{:.2f}\%'.format(s*100)).to_latex()
```

which gives

```latex
\begin{tabular}{lr}
 & c \\
0 & 23.23\% \\
1 & 52.54\% \\
2 & 100.00\% \\
\end{tabular}
```